# Java Game not rendering properly

Tags: java

Hello I have a game that you can play(duh). When you start the game a loading screen pops up and on the loading screen I display an image of an eye I drew. In paint.net they eye looks perfect but in game it dose not.

Here is the image in paint.net:

[image]

Here is the image in game:

[image]

I don't understand why the image is all messed up as much. Please help me! Thx.

Comment: maybe if you enabled anti aliasing or that did not help ?

Comment: What do you mean 'all messed up'. What's wrong with the version in your game?

Comment: what is antia aliasing

Comment: if u look at the picture in paint it is a perfect circle

Comment: but the ne in game is not I don't think this is  a good photo to show it wasn't great quality

Comment: nvm I figured it out

Answer (score 2):

Only thing I see wrong is that you made the circle 1 pixel thicker on right and bottom side. That's not problem of your code though, only your drawing skills.